# Keep Google Search Appliance from indexing "latest posts" in Fancier Author Box plugin

Tags: php, wordpress, google-search-appliance

Posted this on [Wordpress.org's Support forum](http://wordpress.org/support/topic/keep-google-search-appliance-from-indexing-latest-posts?replies=1), and haven't heard anything. Hopefully someone here can help!

We use a Google Search Appliance to serve search results on our site, and have had our GSA indexing our WordPress.org blog content for a while. We're finding that some key searches are getting diluted due to keywords being included in blog titles within the Latest Posts area of the Fancier Author Box. I would like to add in the `<!--googleoff:index-->` and `<!--googleon:index-->` tags around either the DIV that is classed "ts-fab-text" or the UL that is classed "ts-fab-latest" to instruct the GSA not to index that content. Could you please advise which file I'd need to go into in the Editor to add this? I've looked through the files and cannot find this markup, but I'm also not a PHP developer, so may be overlooking it.

https://wordpress.org/plugins/fancier-author-box/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are looking for seems to be found at:
plugindirectory\includes\ts-fab-construct-tabs.php , line 127

Comment: Thank you! Not sure why I couldn't find that -- appreciate the help!

Comment: Happy I could be of use :)